# Core Data Insert with Relationship without Subclassed NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, unrecognized-selector

Is it possible to insert a new core data record with the relationships intact and no `NSManagedObject` subclasses?

My setup is like so:

[image]

The code so far is:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

NSManagedObject *author = [NSEntityDescription
                           insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Author"
                           inManagedObjectContext:context];
[author setValue:@"Jim" forKey:@"name"];
[author setValue:@"jim@g.com" forKey:@"email"];

NSManagedObject *topic = [NSEntityDescription
                           insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Topic"
                           inManagedObjectContext:context];
[topic setValue:@"Auto" forKey:@"title"];

NSManagedObject *post = [NSEntityDescription
                                   insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Post"
                                   inManagedObjectContext:context];
[post setValue:@"Test Bank" forKey:@"body"];
[post setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"creationDate"];
[post setValue:@"Testland" forKey:@"title"];

NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

This obviously doesn't add any relationships... I have seen this on another SO post:

```
[[post mutableSetValueForKey:@"Author"] addObject:author];
```

But this gives an `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, property/relationships name are case sensistive (so instead of `@"Author"` use `@"author"`).

The cardinality of your relationship  from `Post` to `Author` is: to-one hence:

```
[post setValue:author forKey:@"author"];
```

should set the relationship.

(the mutable set version will work from `Author` to `Post` where the cardinality is to-many)

Comment: Doh!! I feel like an idiot now! I can't believe it was a case sensitivity issue! I've been trying to figure it out for ages :) Thanks for the help

Comment: We have all been there :)